# Autohotkey reading a csv file with million lines

Tags: scripting, autohotkey

My requirement is to read a CSV file with around million lines by grepping particular string and displaying the output line.

**Example CSV File:**

```
Rob,school,oxford,tennis
James,school,cambridge,cricket
lucy,college,harvard,football
lily,hotel,novotel,golf
..
..
..
1 million lines.
```

**Requirement:**

When i invoke the **AHK** script , it prompts a user input through **InputBox** and takes input as **James school** and it should output as **cambridge**. Similarly input as **lily hotel** and it should output as **novotel**.

I am able to achieve the desired output through below script , but the problem is when i search for a string which is *for example at 1 millionth line* it takes around **5-10 mins** to give me the output.

**Script i wrote:**

```
#SingleInstance, force
#Include C:\Users\mpechett\Desktop\ahk\tf.ahk

InputBox, Name, Search for Name


StringSplit, word_array, Name, %A_Space%, .  ; Omits periods.

pattern = %word_array1%,%word_array2%


Outputline = % TF_Find("C:\Users\mpechett\example.csv", "","", pattern, 1, 1)


MsgBox,%Outputline%
```

***Please help me in improving the performance of my script.***

Comment: I would [sort](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Sort.htm) the contents in alphabetical order and then [split](http://filesplit.org/) this big file into several smaller files (a.csv, b.csv etc).

Comment: That is one way of doing it.
Instead of splitting files, isnt any way to improve the speed?

Answer (score 0):

If You use a RAMDISK you can speedup your Search Results. I can not see what your tf.ahk Script is, but 5-10 mins is to long, 1 - the loop code in the tf.ahk File is not good 2 - or it does do everytime a search from out your HardDisk c: and not from out your ram memory.

You can Download the Freeware From Here [Imdisk](http://virtualkeystarterblog.com/top-20-best-software-on-windows-system/)

- The RAMDISK is a virtual Harddisk, that is placed into Your Ram Memory.
- a RAMDISK is +-100x Faster then a Harddisk.

First Install IMDISK on your Windows System, then you can simple install/put/copy **any Application** or put/copy any **csv file** to the Ramdisk [example - z:\example.csv]

z:\example.csv

```
Rob,school,oxford,tennis
James,school,cambridge,cricket
lucy,college,harvard,football
lily,hotel,novotel,golf
..
..
..
1 million lines.
```

Note : With this AHK Keyboard Shortcut Macro Script, you can type - for Example : **college,harvard** and then it will do a search in NotePad and it will give the result Value **football** (This is only a example to test it out, for bigger files you will need to Chance the code a little bit and use a other Application([SpeadSheat program](http://virtualkeystarterblog.com/top-20-best-software-on-windows-system/)) that can Handle Bigger Files)

Search.ahk

```
; this Script works on Windows 10 system.
; You can Click key, F1 to EXIT

#SingleInstance, force

run notepad.exe z:\example.csv
WinWaitActive,example.csv, , 2



loop
{

InputBox,Clipboard,Search for Name
sleep 100
send ^{Home} ;goto Top of the Page
sleep 100
send ^f ;goto the Find box 
sleep 100
send ^v ;paste Clipboard Value
sleep 100
send {enter}
sleep 1500 ;You can change this sleep codeline - How bigger the search, how larger the sleep must be.
send {esc}
sleep 100

;If you want to Select the Whole Search Line - you can use this code.
;send {Home}
;sleep 100
;send +{End}

;If you want to Select the Rigth Site of the Line - you can use this code. 
send {Right}
sleep 100
send +{End}

sleep 100
send ^c ;copy the Search LineValue to Clipboard 
LineValue = %Clipboard%
sleep 100
word_array := StrSplit(LineValue, ",")
sleep 100
SearchValue := word_array[1]" "       ;word_array[2]" "word_array[3]
sleep 100
MsgBox "SearchValue",%SearchValue%
}

F1::ExitApp
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is pseudocode for a indexed database type solution:**

```
make_index() {
  global file := FileOpen( "database.csv", "r" )
  for each line in database {
    position  := file.pos
    line      := file.readline()
    values    := StrSplit(line)
    key       := make_a_unique_key(values)
    hash[key] := position
  }
  save hash to "database.index"
}

lookup(values) {
  global file, hash
  file.seek( hash[ make_a_unique_key( values )])
  return file.readline()
}
```

See: Manual entry for [File object](https://autohotkey.com/docs/objects/File.htm)